# how to prevent layout from any changes when device is rotated?

Tags: android, layout, orientation

I think I have question that looks similar to many old questions but it is not the same.

I would like the application not to change layout orientation when device is rotated while application is running.
This:

```
android:screenOrientation = "portrait"
```

...does NOT do the trick. I don't want to have application with fixed orientation. I would like just to prevent it from changing when application is working.

This:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

...does NOT do the trick. When set, application does not restart, layout does not change to another but current layout is rotated and stretched according to new device orientation.

All what I would like to achieve is to choose proper layout according to orientation when activity starts and after that remain the same layout and the same layout orientation until application finishes.

Anybody knows how to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to restrict your application in same orientation until the application finished , use this code once createInstance called , then use appropriate layout in corresponding resource folder , for portrait res/layout and for landscape use res/layout-land...

```
 Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

    int orientation = display.getOrientation();

    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    if(orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android system handles rotations automatically for you by destroying and re-creating the Activity. Andrdoid calls this a "configuration change", there are several that can occur (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges).

This is not what you want, so you can indicate the kind of configuration changes you want to handle manually in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<Activity ... android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

Probably then you want to override `Activity.onConfigurationChanged(Configuration)` to handle configuration changes as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to find out the screen orientation in onCreate() and then set that orientation:

```
/* First, get the Display from the WindowManager */
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();

/* Now we can retrieve all display-related infos */
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();
int orientation = display.getOrientation();
```

and then set the orientation accordingly :   setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_XXXXX)

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
package com.exercise.AndroidOrientation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class AndroidOrientationActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button buttonSetPortrait = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setPortrait);
    Button buttonSetLandscape = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setLandscape);

    buttonSetPortrait.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}});

    buttonSetLandscape.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }});
}
}
```